# "Für", "gegen", "um" — which to use when?

Tags: meaning, difference, preposition, accusative

All three accusative prepositions *für, gegen*, and *um* can mean "for" in certain situations. 
Can anybody give examples when to use which of the three?

Comment: The question is too broad, and the answer would be monstruous. There are prepositions paired with adjectives (geeignet für, schädlich für, immun gegen, etc.), prepositions paired with verbs (sich kümmern um, danken für, sich entscheiden gegen) substantives paired with prepositions (Entscheidung für, Kampf gegen, Krieg um) usw. Other than learning wich preposition corresponds to which verb, I don't find a better mehtod.

Answer (score 8):

> Superman was asked *for* an autograph *for* Mary. He said: "I only do this *for* money."
>
> Superman wurde *um* ein Autogramm *für* Mary gebeten. Er sagte: „Ich mach das nur *gegen* Geld.“

The `for` in the second sentence can also be translated by `für`:

> […] Er sagte: „Ich mach das nur *für* Geld.“

Answer (score 6):

There is no rule when to use which one, especially in case of `um`. You must simply learn which verb demands one of these three words. Some verbs and phrases use `um` and there is no reason why:

```
Um Gottes willen!
um einen Gefallen bitten
```

In my feel for language I tend to think `um` in the meaning of this topic here is a relict of former times and only used rarely in certain fixed phrases, but I may be wrong.

Both ones, `für` and `gegen` are used for all other stuff where `um` is not used. I cannot find an example where `um` can be replaced by one of them.

`Gegen` is used when there is an exchange of things, commonly something for the price of another, and it shows the two *directions* of exchanging, for example `Ware gegen Geld`.

`Für` in the meaning of "for" is commonly used to tell the addressed receiver ("Für wen?") of the result, for example `für alle`, or the cost itself ("Für was?"). But usually you can use `für` also as replacement of `gegen`, it more underlines the price in contrast to `gegen` which underlines the exchange, but not inevitably. For example `Ich mach das nur für Geld` accents a bit more what the price is ("Geld"), and `Ich mach das nur gegen Geld` accents a bit more that there **is** actually a price and that it's not for free.

Comment: Quelle: http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=23,761,1 : `um` hat ursprünglich eine räumliche Bedeutung. Die Verwendung in anderen Bedeutungen ist aber so alt, dass ihr Ursprung zur Zeit unklar ist. Diese Verwendung blieb aber nicht mehr generell erhalten, sondern nur noch in Form einzelner Verbgruppen oder Phrasen.

Comment: You should change the last paragraph a bit. At the moment, it sounds as if one could exchange `für` by `gegen` in nearly all circumstances. But this is only the case, if `für` has the meaning of the cost itself.

Comment: @Toscho: Gib mir mal bitte ein Bsp.

Comment: `um etwas bitten` hat keine räumliche Bedeutung. Ähnliche Bedeutung findet man noch in `um etwas flehen`, `sich um etwas bringen` und eine dritte Bedeutungsgruppe findet man in `sich um etwas handeln`, `um etwas gehen`, `sich um etwas sorgen`, wobei ich mir gut vorstellen kann, wie diese Bedeutungsgruppe z.B. in einem Thing aus der räumlichen Bedeutung entstanden ist.

Comment: @Toscho: das denke ich auch. Ich glaube sogar, dass auch sich um etwas bringen und um etwas bitten räumlich interpretierbar sind. Wenn ich mich lokal "um" etwas bringe, also drumherum bewege, dann bin ich nicht da. Ich bin daran vorbei gegangen und habe es nicht. Um etwas bitten könnte man auf einen Gebetskreis oder auf Tänze um das Feuer zurückführen... allerdings alles nur Spekulationen.:)

Comment: Jungs, das ist auch höchst interessant, aber mit Bsp. meinte ich Kommentar 2 (für <-> gegen)

Comment: @falkb `Das Geschenk ist für Anna.` vs. `Das Geschenk ist gegen Anna.`

Comment: @Toscho: Wir wollen doch aber `gegen` mit `für` ersetzen. Im Anna-Bsp. würde das heißen, dass man Anna eintauschen will, um ein Geschenk zu erhalten. ;) Das ist also kein Bsp.

Comment: @falkb Ah, jetzt verstehe ich, was du meinst. Da fällt mir kein Beispiel ein, in dem `gegen` tatsächlich als eigenständiges Wort auftaucht. Im Kompositum `Gegenwert` ließe es sich nicht ersetzen, aber darum geht es ja nicht. Der letzte Absatz ist aber trotzdem missverständlich.

Comment: Dann weiß ich leider nicht, was ich auf deinen Kommentar 2 hin tun soll. Kannst du den Abschnitt bitte editieren. Danach können wir die ganzen entsprechenden Kommentar dazu wieder löschend aufräumen. Danke :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can’t think of any example where you’d translate “for” with “um”, but to give first examples:

1. `I will do this for you.` translates to `Ich werde das für dich tun.`
2. `I will do this for money.` translates to `Ich werde das gegen Geld tun.`

I will add further explanations later.

Comment: Pons: He did it for the fame -> Er tat es, um berühmt zu werden.

Comment: @Em1: That’s not a preposition, though.

Comment: Er tat es um des Rumes Willen.

Comment: @emanuel Sehr gut! Aber „… Willen“.

Comment: @K.Stm.: Ich verstehe nicht ganz... wo ist der Fehler :)

Comment: @Emanuel Es wäre wörtlich eher „He did it for the sake of fame.“ und nicht „He did for the fame“. Daher ist das ein bisschen geschummelt.